# Google Chrome 84 + Google Maps InfoWindow: Prevent webpage jump when clicking close button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There seems to be an odd behavior in Google Chrome v84 when closing an InfoWindow in a Google Map embedded in a webpage using the JavaScript API:

Whenever the page is not scrolled to the top, clicking the close button on an InfoWindow makes the scroll position of the page jump by `15px` down.

This did not happen in Version 83 and lower.

- New issue in the tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/163214518
- JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/hb1dx5a3/

Here is a simple reproducible example. Scroll the page down until the map is in the viewport, click the marker, close the Infowindow, the page will scroll down by `15px`.

```js
function initialize() {

  const mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
  };

  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    map: map,
    title: 'Nothing here'
  });

  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Hello World'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
    displayVerticalOffset();
  });

  window.onscroll = function() {
    displayVerticalOffset();
  };
}

function displayVerticalOffset() {
  document.getElementById('pageYOffset').innerHTML = 'Vertical offset: ' + window.pageYOffset + 'px'
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  margin-top: 800px;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
}

#pageYOffset {
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="pageYOffset"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

Comment: *this is not an programming error on my side* - it is, unless you prove us otherwise by providing a [mcve].

Comment: I guess i phrased that wrong. What i meant was: "To be sure i am not alone with this problem.". To make it reproducible, i added a simple code sample.

Comment: Ok, I confirm this behavior on Chrome Version 84.0.4147.105 on MacOS.

Comment: I edited your question to include a stack snippet allowing to reproduce the issue and created a new [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/163214518) in their tracker. You should star the issue if you want to receive updates about it.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thank you for your help! I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Just applied a temporary solution from duplicate of @MrUpsidown from Google Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/163170951

You can add the css property "overflow-anchor: none;" to your map container and this behavior might be prevented.

Answer (score 14):

add overflow-anchor:none to parent, here is

```
#map-canvas {
  overflow-anchor:none;
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for hours, thank you!!